# Network Time Protocol V4 -- Count of extension fields in a packet

Tags: ntp

I am learning network time protocol and went roughly through RFC 5905 from [IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#section-7.3).

It states that `The packet format consists of three components: the header itself, one or more optional extension fields, and an optional message authentication code (MAC)` from section 7.3, however it seems that there is nothing about count of these optional extension fields in the encoding scheme. And to my understanding without this information the whole packet cannot be reliably read because the total length is unknown if there are any extension fields.

Please anyone point out what I missed or misunderstood.

Comment: What about section 7.5, which explains the format of the extension, including the `Length` field?

Comment: @Progman the ````Length```` field in section 7.5 is the length of an individual extension field, not the length of all fields or the whole packet.

Comment: These optional data is at the end, you can read them until you reached the end. Keep in mind that the UDP packet has a length field.